# Can a blood hawk animal companion be commanded to carry around their beast master?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions

Let's say a gnome Beast Master ranger chooses a Blood Hawk animal companion, is the companion able to follow the order to pick up and carry the PC?

I'm more looking at the possible issue of commanding a companion to carry something - since I don't think that's an explicit action that can be commanded.

Comment: Player in this case, but more looking at the possible issue of commanding a companion to carry something - since i dont think thats an explicit action that can be commanded? Does it require an aparatus like a harness that the player chooses to grapple onto?

Comment: Related questions on [Do the rules for carrying capacity apply to animal companions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/do-the-rules-for-carrying-capacity-apply-to-animal-companions) and [Can my familiar fly with a small person?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107318/can-my-familiar-fly-with-a-small-person) and [Does the player have control of a ranger's companion?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116975/does-the-player-have-control-of-a-rangers-companion)

Comment: Does the last link I gave answer your question? Ultimately, it seems like the same thing.

Comment: Not directly, but i would interpret to mean - yes the companion can voluntarily be commanded to carry a PC, or anything.

Comment: Its similar but a different question, the answer happens to be yes (the same), but it could have been different.

Comment: If that previous question does not answer yours, then yours seems a bit unclear to me. Your title is "can [it] be commanded" and your body is "is [it] able...?" Then your clarifying comment is "is this command available for a PC to give?"

Comment: Yes, i phrased it this way because ofcourse a person “can” say anything (command) but the main point is - is the animal able to fulfill the command?. IMO This question is not a duplicate of the other question because an animal companion is not a familiar, they have different rules for how they are controlled, although the outcome happens to be similar.

Comment: Yes but each question, while related, is a different problem and some do already have answers here. You may find more success if you narrow your wording to the specific problem you need addressed :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Possibly, if you're not a heavier-than-average gnome in a lot of armor

A Blood Hawk has a strength score of 6.
This means they can carry 90 lbs, because they are small, not tiny. (6*15)

A gnome's weight averages 40 to 45 pounds. So if the gnome is carrying less than their own bodyweight in goods and equipment, they should be light enough for the Blood Hawk to carry. If they are heavier than that, the Blood Hawk would only be able to drag the gnome around.

Considering the beast *obeys your commands as best it can*, 'carry me up' seems like something it is both physically capable of, and something that falls under the commands you can give it.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** according to the Rangers Companion feature of the Beast Master archetype, the companion is trained and works in partnership with the Ranger.

> The beast obeys your commands as best as it can. (PHB p93)

Since the carry rules apply to any character including a beast companion, [the beast can carry](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/148637/53875). Therefor the bloodhawk will obey a beast master’s command to carry them.

This depends on the beast being strong enough to carry the PC. We can look at the carrying rules in more detail.

> Your carrying capacity is your Strength score
>   multiplied by 15 *[in pounds]*. (PHB p176)

[Bloodhawk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/blood-hawk) has a strength of 6, so can carry 90 pounds.

Using the Variant Encumbrance rules, carry weight is 5 times Strength score before being encumbered. Carry in excess of 10 times Strength and become heavily encumbered.

With the variant rule, the bloodhawk can carry 30lb’s before suffering a speed penalty of 10 feet. Carry more than 60lb’s and speed drops 20 feet, suffer disadvantage on ability checks, attack rolls, and saving throws that use Str, Dex, or Con.